# vscode run unit tests

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I have an existing project set up so that `npm run test` runs all unit tests or `npm run test [...files]` will run specific files only.

I would like to set up vscode to work with this, but I am completely lost. There is `launch.json` and `tasks.json` and it's totally unclear what each do or how to set them up properly. It seems that `launch.json` configures the "Run and debug" menu, and tasks configures tasks that don't seem to appear anywhere except in the command palette??

Which is the correct one to use here?

Ideally I want a button to appear somewhere that I can just click to run the tests in the currently open test file. Is this possible?

I have heard that you can use `${file}` for the currently open file, but I'm not sure if this is a real thing or whether it works in launch or tasks or both.

I have also heard that there is a default `Ctrl-Shift-T` shortcut for running a "test" task, but I have been unable to get this to work. Is this a real thing? If so how do you set it up?

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined these npm run scripts in `package.json` (in the root of your workspace) you will get an `NPM SCRIPTS` view in the Explorer Bar

Just click the script you want